# vuejs add comma to numbers while typing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to add separator in my numbers while i'm typing but it doesn't work.

## Code

```
<el-input-number v-model="form.qty" style="width: 100%;" id="test" placeholder="Quantity" controls-position="right" v-on:keyup="handleChange" :min="1"></el-input-number>

methods: {
    handleChange: function(value) {
        let vm = this;
        console.log(value);
        const result = value.toString().replace(/\D/g, "")
            .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            Vue.nextTick()
            .then(function () {
                vm.form.qty = result
            });
    },
}
```

[image: one]

## issue

Currently when i'm typing numbers **no comma adds to input field** but when i'm **sending my values to back-end it sends it with commas**.

## What I need

What I need is the exact opposite behavior than I explained above,

1. show numbers with commas in view
2. send it to back-end without commas

**Any idea?**

Comment: To send clean value i recommend you to use @ input event. For filtering value use @ change event

Comment: @MaksimTikhonov ok! i have changed it to `@change="handleChange"` now what? still i can't get any update in my input field :/

Comment: so you have to format value on change event and clean it on inout before sending to backend

Comment: ...........how?

Comment: If you want to send clean integer use: const cleanValue = parseInt(value.split(',').join('')); 
If you want to display number with comma's use String(value).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");

Comment: @MaksimTikhonov you didn't get it right bro, I can get my number with commas, the issue is i cannot get it in my input field. `the replace part is working. returning part is not working`

Comment: Is it possible in el-input-number? If not try common text input

Comment: it is text type by default  screenshot https://ibb.co/MkWkVMD

Comment: Why do you use $nextTick.then function? I always use it this manner this.$nextTick(() => { ... })

Comment: And maybe it not needed here

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just reactivity problem instead of using = use $set.

```
handleChange(value) {
        console.log(value);
        let vm = this;
        let res = value.toString().replace(/\D/g, "")
            .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        console.log(res)
        this.$set(this.form,'num',res);

      }
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/PratikPatel227/tLx3z96a/28/

while sending data use - `this.form.num.replace(/,/g, '')`

Comment: I don't think reactivity is the problem. Simple assignment should work fine here. Also, you didn't solve the second part of the OP's "WHAT I NEED" section, i.e. "send it to back-end without commas". Please note that I did **not** down-vote you. Just leaving a comment.

Comment: unfortunetly it didn't work, result was same as my own code, oh i also did change your code from num to qty ` this.$set(this.form,'qty',res);` i was aware :)

Comment: you also need to change <el-input-number> to <el-input> Please refer the fiddle it's working in fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use ElementUI, so I can't confirm that `el-input-number` will accept a formatted string value. It's possible that that component internally strips all non-numeric characters from the `value` prop. However, the solution below works on standard text inputs.

In order to display something different than you store, you need to split the `v-model` directive back into its original parts. `v-model` is just a shortcut for binding `value` and `@input` in a single directive. You should store the un-formatted number in your `form.qty` field, but supply the `el-input-number` component with the formatted number via a computed property, like this:

```
<template>
  <!-- INSTEAD OF v-model, use :value and @input -->
  <el-input-number :value="formattedQty" @input="handleQtyInput" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      form: {
        qty: "0",
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    formattedQty () {
      //Add the commas back to the string
      let qty = this.form.qty + ""
      return qty.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    }
  },

  methods: {
    handleQtyInput (newValue) {
      //Make sure the stored qty is not formatted
      this.form.qty = newValue.toString().replace(/\D/g, "")
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: it says: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.form.qty.replace is not a function"`

Comment: This is probably caused by a null or numeric value in the initial state of `this.form.qty`. I have updated the `formattedQty` computed property with one way to handle this case.

Comment: hi thanks, but nothing is happening, i won't get error neither formatted number :/

Comment: Does the unformatted number show in the input field? If so, the `el-input-number` doesn't allow formatted text.

Comment: yes it does, and when i use `el-input` instead of `el-input-number` it shows formatted number BUT after i click outside of my input not while i'm typing numbers

Comment: Ok, in that case bind to the keyup event instead of the input event on the component.